# how to reset a jquery animation to start over?

Tags: jquery, methods, reset

I have built a nice piece of code, some animation and some click/hover events, quite a small  row of them. I intend to use it on multiple html-documents (it is a game, you have to get right answer and proceed with next question), built together in another html with full-page-slider (I don't want to load DOM multiple times, makes no sense): the unsolved question is: how to reset the code without actually reloading it? how to make it to clear everything so far and start over?
I am a beginner, building stuff upon others snippets. I guess it must be something so easy and basic that nobody answered it... The stuff to animate back all what is done previously is no good: too much stuff and binding and unbinding.

Answer (score 22):

I had an animation that was keeping the position each time the code ran. To fix it I used:

```
function(){ $('.target').removeAttr('style'); }
```

so my code was something like:

```
$('#target').animate({
  opacity: 'toggle',
  top: '+=100',
  }, 1000, function() {
  $('#target').removeAttr('style'); 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

For jQuery you can use .finish(), and before that, to reset you need a few parameters to the .stop() method.

```
$(element).stop(true, true);
```

https://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: this do not work, it just leave the transformed element there... :-/

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way: (not sure if it's entirely right, though)

```
$(element).stop();
$(element).clearQueue();
$(element).delay(20).animate({ ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

$(element).stop(), then re-run your animation.

Comment: This doesn't work. It will not rerun or start over once it is finished.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy answer since it all depends on what you've done, what state you need to reset, what UI elements need to be reset and so on. I guess you have to build your own reset method that sets all things to their initial state or... you could take the easy path and just reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for patient answers. Both are right:

- in case of one animation the stop method works.
- in case of multiple chained animations - sorry, there is no easy way. Reload if you want a short but not so elegant solution. To do it properly - learn javascript to build the logical chain of functions. You can't run long with just jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.finish()`.
Example (try spamming the button):

```
$('button').on('click', function(event) {
  $("div").finish();
  $("div").fadeOut(1000);
});
```